# Setting up a background image in react JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a file in my public folder of react project known as `backgrund.jpg`

I am trying to add  it in `styles.css` of public folder to set it up as background image.

Here is the code for the same:

```
background-image:url("%PUBLIC_URL%/background.jpg");
```

The above code doesn't change anything however when I try:

```
background-image:url('https://i1.wp.com/sociallover.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/nature-images.png');
```

or

```
background-color: greenyellow;
```

both of them work perfectly. To give you a better picture, here's how the files are located:

[image]

Do let me know what exactly it is that I am doing wrong?

In the inspector I get this message:
`GET http://localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/background.jpg 400 (Bad Request)`

Additional things i did:

1. did a npm start after stopping the old server.
2. checked for the file name extension to ensure that my jpg matches with background.jpg.

Comment: In case you use `background-image:url("%PUBLIC_URL%/background.jpg");`, what output do you have - did you check the result in your browser console using Inspector?

Comment: I get GET http://localhost:3000/%PUBLIC_URL%/background.jpg 400 (Bad Request). Do i do an `npm start` again?

Comment: `%PUBLIC_URL%` only works in the index.html file. You don't need it in CSS files, just use a relative URL.

Comment: by relative url you mean `background.jpg`?

Comment: Did your image is available via `https://your-site.name/background.jpg`? Maybe try to use `background-image:url("background.jpg");` only, due to styles and image are in the same folder?

Comment: thanks guys, using `background.jpg` worked.

Comment: Yes, the image file is in the same directory as the CSS file so there's no point in using a full URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Guy Incognito and @Ihor Vyspianky, I solved the problem by replacing:

```
background-image:url("%PUBLIC_URL%/background.jpg");
```

to

```
background-image:url("background.jpg");
```